# iOS 8 Swift: Trying to delete data in detail view of table view

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, xcode6

I used the single-view template and created a navigation controller with a ViewController that's a table view with a list of continents (read in from a plist). Clicking on a row pushes to a DetailViewController with a table view that shows some of the countries in that continent. In this DetailViewController I implemented the Edit button so a country could be deleted. Up to this point everything works great. Then when you tap the Back button to return to the continents table, when you select the same continent, the country you just deleted is listed again. I had written the same exact app in Objective-C in iOS 6 and the country that you deleted remained gone. Same problem exists when I reorder rows as well.

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

var continentData = NSDictionary()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("continents", ofType: "plist")
    continentData = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path!)
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return continentData.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    let continents = continentData.allKeys as [String]
    cell.textLabel?.text=continents[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier=="countrysegue"{
        var countryVC:DetailViewController=segue.destinationViewController as DetailViewController
        let indexPath:NSIndexPath=tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
        var continents = continentData.allKeys as [String]
        countryVC.title=continents[indexPath.row]
        countryVC.countryList=continentData.objectForKey(countryVC.title!) as [String]
    }
}
```

Then the DetailViewController:

```
class DetailViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate  {

var countryList = [String]()

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    //tableView.reloadData()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return countryList.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text=countryList[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        countryList.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
//not implemented
}
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let fromRow=fromIndexPath.row
    let toRow=toIndexPath.row
    let moveCountry=countryList[fromRow]
    countryList.removeAtIndex(fromRow)
    countryList.insert(moveCountry, atIndex: toRow)
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

I haven't been able to find anything online where the delete is being done in the detail view controller. My guess is that in Objective-C NSMutableArray was passed by reference and in Swift Array is being passed by value. What's the best way to get this to work, use an unwind segue and method to pass the array back to the master view controller? Thanks in advance. - AJP

I also thought the problem might be that the array was being passed by value and not by reference. So I created a data model class

```
class Continents {
    var continentData = NSMutableDictionary()
    var continents = [String]()
    var countries = [String]()
}
```

and created an instance of it in the master view controller

```
var continentList=Continents()
```

and in my detail view controller

```
var continentCountries = Continents()
```

Then I updated prepareForSegue

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier=="countrysegue"{
            var countryVC:DetailViewController=segue.destinationViewController as DetailViewController
            let indexPath:NSIndexPath=tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
            countryVC.title=continentList.continents[indexPath.row]
            countryVC.continentCountries.countries=continentList.continentData.objectForKey(countryVC.title!) as [String]
        }
    }
```

In the detail I updated the following to handle the delete:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        NSLog("\(continentCountries.countries)")
        if editingStyle == .Delete {
            continentCountries.countries.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        }}
```

Still having the same behavior, the delete works but the next time I got back in to that continent the country I deleted is still there. How can I make sure it's being passed by reference using Swift? Thanks.

As suggested I now pass the whole object and the selected index.

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier=="countrysegue"{
        var countryVC=segue.destinationViewController as DetailViewController
        let indexPath:NSIndexPath=tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
        countryVC.title=continentList.continents[indexPath.row]
        countryVC.continentCountries=continentList
        countryVC.selectedContinent=indexPath.row
    }
```

In the detail view controller:

```
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    continentCountries.continents = continentCountries.continentData.allKeys as [String]
    let chosenContinent = continentCountries.continents[selectedContinent]
    continentCountries.countries = continentCountries.continentData.objectForKey(chosenContinent) as [String]
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

But the behavior is still the same. Is it the casting to an Array? Or how I delete a row?

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        continentCountries.countries.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    } 
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From *The Swift Programming Language*

> **Assignment and Copy Behavior for Strings, Arrays, and Dictionaries**
>
> Swift’s String, Array, and Dictionary types are implemented as
>   structures. This means that strings, arrays, and dictionaries are
>   copied when they are assigned to a new constant or variable, or when
>   they are passed to a function or method.
>
> This behavior is different from NSString, NSArray, and NSDictionary in
>   Foundation, which are implemented as classes, not structures.
>   NSString, NSArray, and NSDictionary instances are always assigned and
>   passed around as a reference to an existing instance, rather than as a
>   copy.

So, you either need to pass an `NSArray` or perhaps, abstract your array into a data model class and pass the reference to the data model (which is just a  lightweight wrapper around the array)

**Update**

You cannot pass a Swift array by reference because it is a struct and structs are always copied.

You will need to pass your data model class reference and the index path to your detail view controller.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier=="countrysegue"{
            var countryVC:DetailViewController=segue.destinationViewController as DetailViewController
            let indexPath:NSIndexPath=tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
            countryVC.title=continentList.continents[indexPath.row]
            countryVC.continentCountries=continentList
            countryVC.selectedContinentIndex=indexPath.row
        }
    }
```

Then your detail view controller will need to use the selectedContinentIndex to find the right countries in the model.

A better data model might be -

```
class Continents {
    var continents = [String]()
    var countries = Dictionary<String>,[String]>()
}
```

An array of continents and an dictionary of country arrays, keyed by continent.

Comment: I also thought the problem might be that the array was being passed by value and not by reference. So I created a data model class

Comment: and created instances of the class in both the master and detail view controllers. See update to code above.

Comment: I thought about passing the whole object but didn't think of the index path. I do that now as you have above. In the detail:    `override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        continentCountries.continents = continentCountries.continentData.allKeys as [String]
        let chosenContinent = continentCountries.continents[selectedContinent]
        continentCountries.countries = continentCountries.continentData.objectForKey(chosenContinent) as [String]
        tableView.reloadData()
    } ` but the same behavior. Is it creating a copy when I'm casting it? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. You need to manipulate the arrays directly in the dictionary. As soon as you assign the array to another variable you get a copy. It is probably easier to use NSArrays :)

Comment: That makes sense and I can do that everywhere except I can't figure out how to actually delete a country in `tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath)`  without casting to an Array. Using NSArray is my last resort, was trying to do this as much in Swift and Swift classes as possible. Thanks.

Comment: It should be something like self.continentCountries[self.continents.continentData[self.selectedContinentIndex]].removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)

Comment: Got the delete working with `continentCountries.continentData[chosenContinent]?.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath.row)` and the move working with        `continentCountries.continentData[chosenContinent]?.removeObjectAtIndex(fromRow)
        continentCountries.continentData[chosenContinent]?.insertObject(moveCountry, atIndex: toRow)` Thanks for the help.